# Ruby nested has error undefined method `[]' using variables

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm trying to create something to pull my schedule from an email and set it up to be added to Google Calendars automatically. I'm trying to get it in steps as I also learn Ruby, so I'm not looking for a solution to the complete thing, only assistance with this error. As far as I can tell, the assignment (or at least calling the item) should be functioning in the loop.

I've cleaned the code up from all the prints I was using to try to see if it was my mistake, but the variables I was using give exactly what I expect inside the loop, and the nested array call gives what I expect outside the loop as well. Using the direct name (schedule["Mon"]["Lunch"]) gives the result I expect, but schedule[currDay]["Lunch"] does not.

```rb
str = "Monday, July 22, 2019 (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
    Lunch_101306    10:30 AM    11:00 AM
    Ready - Onsite_101306   11:00 AM    12:20 PM"
arr = str.split(/\n/)

schedule = {}
currDay = ''
arr.each {|x|   
    #if it matches day of week, set as current day, and create hash entry in schedule
    if x.match?(/(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)/) then
        currDay = x.scan(/(Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)/)
        schedule[currDay[0][0]] = {"Start" => 'Default', "Lunch" => 'Default', "End" => 'Default'}

    #else if the entry has lunch ready or break in it
    elsif x.match?(/(?:Lunch|Ready|Break)/) then
        #store information in temp for name of line, and groups for start and end time.
        tempArg = x.scan(/(Lunch|Ready|Break).*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}).*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2})/)

        #if it's lunch, add this to schedule's current day entry for lunch
        if tempArg[0][0] == "Lunch" then
            puts schedule[currDay]["Lunch"]
                        #schedule[currDay]["Lunch"] = tempArg[0][1]
        end
        #check for ready / break
    end
}
```

Expected `puts schedule[currDay]["Lunch"]` to output "Default", though the objective of this part is to assign the second group from tempArg over this value. Instead, I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/Users/User/Documents/Testing/test.rb:17:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Users/User/Documents/Testing/test.rb:17:in `each'
C:/Users/User/Documents/Testing/test.rb:31:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that `currDay` stores `[["Mon"]]` and not just `"Mon"`, so instead of doing `schedule[currDay]["Lunch"]` you need to do `schedule[currDay[0][0]]["Lunch"]` or better just store `"Mon"` inside `currDay` to not confuse yourself:

```rb
currDay = x.scan(/(Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)/)[0][0]
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Can't believe I didn't try that when I was messing with it. Thanks a lot! I assume that I could also do something like
```
tempArg = x.scan(/(Lunch|Ready|Break).*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2}).*?(\d{1,2}:\d{2})/)[0]
```
to remove that extra layer?